# Target all divs two layers below

Tags: css, styled-components

I am trying to set all divs 'two layers below' to `display: block` when a user hovers over an element. The following code works however, I just want to target the two divs that are two layers down. The reason I need to update to just target the `divs` that are two layers down as is this is a multi level dropdown menu so the html is generated recursively.

My code is as follows, any questions let me know.

```
const ListItem = styled(div)`
   position: relative;
   &:hover {
      & * {
        display: block;
      }
   } 
`

... Component ....
return (
   <ListItem>
      <p>Example</p>
      <div className='wrapper'>
          // I want to set these 2 divs to `display: block`
          <div style={{display: 'none'}}>
            <p>One</p>
          </div>
          <div style={{display: 'none'}}>
              <p>Two</p>
          </div>
      </div>
   <ListItem>
);
```

Comment: which one is the Trigger element?

Comment: `ListItem` on hover currently displays everything that is underneath. As I said with the code above this works, the issue is it is setting elements below these to be `display: block` aswell

Comment: Well then use child instead of descendant selectors in the appropriate places … and be more specific as to what you want to target in the first place. Saying you want to match `div` and then using `*` doesn’t really match up to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
const ListItem = styled(div)`
   position: relative;
   &:hover {
      & > .wrapper > div {
        display: block;
      }
   }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the ListItem a class or id?
Then I would only use simple css code, which could work as follows:

```
<ListItem className='list'>
  <p>Example</p>
  <div className='wrapper'>
      <div>
        <p>One</p>
      </div>
      <div>
          <p>Two</p>
      </div>
  </div>
<ListItem>
```

CSS:

```
.list .wrapper > div {
  display: none;
}

.list:hover .wrapper > div {
  display: block;
}
```